# jQuery UI slider not working properly with Google Maps InfoBubble.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use the jQuery UI slider with the Google Maps [infobubble.js](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/infobubble/src/infobubble.js?r=198), but seem to have run into a problem. When you click and try to drag the slider inside the info bubble window, it does not seem to work. However, if you click on the slider handle, move your mouse cursor outside the window to drag up and down, then it works fine. See the JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HU8nH/). The code is listed below:

```
var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-35.397, 150.644);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: mapCenter,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-35, 150),
    draggable: true
});
var bubble = new InfoBubble({
    maxWidth: 300,
});
bubble.addTab("", "<div id='slider' style='height: 100px;'></div>");

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    google.maps.event.addListener(bubble, 'domready', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#slider").slider({
                orientation: "vertical",
                range: "min",
                min: 0,
                max: 80,
                value: 60,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#value").html(ui.value);
                }
            });
        }, 200);
    });
    bubble.open(map, marker);
});
```

I am not sure how to debug this issue. Is it somehow related to a click event?

Comment: Not the click event, it's probably to do with the drag. The Maps API listens for the drag event to move the map around, so you somehow would have to override that listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, solved it - with a caveat.

*tl;dr: You won't be able to select things in the InfoBubble, but the jQuery slider will work.*

- [Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HU8nH/1/).

---

The `mousemove` & `touchmove` event-bubbling is being cancelled by the infobubble.js.
You need that bubble to happen for jQuery UI to hook onto it.. So.. You'll have to edit the infobubble.js code.

#### Here's how!

Grab a copy of [infobubble.js](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/src/infobubble.js) and plonk it into your page as a local copy.

Then, comment out the following lines:

```
InfoBubble.prototype.addEvents_ = function() {
  // We want to cancel all the events so they do not go to the map
  var events = ['mousedown', 'mousemove', 'mouseover', 'mouseout', 'mouseup',
      'mousewheel', 'DOMMouseScroll', 'touchstart', 'touchend', 'touchmove',
      'dblclick', 'contextmenu', 'click'];

  var bubble = this.bubble_;
  this.listeners_ = [];
  for (var i = 0, event; event = events[i]; i++) {
    this.listeners_.push(
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(bubble, event, function(e) {

      /*
       * The bubble that's being cancelled is causing your issues.
         I've commenting this out, but you can remove specific events from the array above.

        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
          e.stopPropagation();
        }

       */

      })
    );
  }
};
```